# Importing .CSV using a list in R

Tags: r, list, csv

so I have 29 data files that I want to load into R. The files are called "1.csv", "2.csv" etc. all the way to 29. Here is the code depicting what I'm trying to do:

```
file.number <- c(1:29)
"the value in file.number".data <- read.csv("the value in file.number"".csv")
```

Basically I am looking for a way to load code based on a list, and label it accordingly. Is this possible?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: `setNames(lapply(paste0(1:29, ".csv"), read.csv), paste0(1:29, ".data"))` might do it

Comment: This worked quite nicely! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would probably work

```
dfList <- setNames(lapply(paste0(1:29, ".csv"), read.csv), paste0(1:29, ".data"))
```

Now you've got a named list of 29 data frames.  Then you can access each individual data frame with the `$` operator, e.g. `dfList$"4.data"`.  Note that you'll need quotes or backticks since you've chosen to begin the names with a digit.  You can avoid that by using `[[` to access the elements i.e. `dfList[["4.data"]]`, or changing to different names such as `paste0("data", 1:29)`, or any name that doesn't begin with a digit.

Another option would be `Map`

```
Map(read.csv, paste0(1:29, ".csv"))
```

This will automatically set the names to the names of the file being read i.e. `1.csv`, `2.csv`, etc.  But again, backticks or quotes would be needed to access the elements with the `$` operator because the names begin with digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
listwithdfs <- lapply(1:29, function(x) read.csv(paste0(x, ".csv"))  )
names(listwithdfs) <- 1:29
```

better to only have one single object in workspace.
now you can index with

```
listwithdfs[[13]]
```

Comment: I tried this, but for whatever reason it assumes there is a space between "1" and ".csv" "1 .csv".

Comment: Setting the names as numbers is a bit pointless when you're just using the list index.

Comment: @BrettCochrane Sounds like you used `paste()` instead of `paste0()`. If you use `paste()` you need to specify `sep = ""`.